# Lus script error - attempt to index a nil value (global 'os')

Tags: lua, lua-scripting-library

I am trying to fetch the UTC time as per below code in my Lua script.

```
local tim = os.time()                                   
local currentUTC = os.date('!%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S', tim)
payload["UTC"] = currentUTC
```

I am getting below error at the 1st line.

```
attempt to index a nil value (global 'os')
```

Please help me in fetching the UTC time without this error.

Comment: If you destroyed ```os``` in some way you can restore it. With: ```os = require('os')``` - Because all whats in ```package.loaded``` is requireable.

Comment: Hi @koyaanisqatsi, Thanks a lot. it worked. I have declared like this local os = require ("os")